# How to force a recheck of Vuelidate validation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

How can I force Vuelidate to re-check a validation?

My use case is that I have a form field where a user can enter the name of a remote directory and I have a Vuelidate validation which checks with the server if that directory exists

```
validations: {
  directory: {
    exists(value) {
      return checkExistsOnServer(value).then(result => result.directoryExists)
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected when the directory field is updated. However, other actions in the app can affect whether this directory exists on the server, so I need a way to be able to manually force this check to re-run in response to various events on the page. How can I force this `exists` check to be re-run without changing the value of the `directory` field?

From the docs, I thought that calling `this.$v.directory.$touch()` would do it, but it doesn't seem to. I've also tried calling `$reset()` before `$touch()`.

I've created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timbarclay/vm716eyu/18/) showing my current unsuccessful attempt.

Answer (score 4):

I've stumbled accross the same issue today. The only way I found to make it work was a bit hacky:

```
const directoryValue = this.$v.directory.$model;
this.$v.directory.$model = null;
this.$v.directory.$model = directoryValue;
```

This seems to force the reevaluation of the field validation.
I'm guessing somewhere in the Vuelidate code there is something that checks that the value has changed before validating, and that's why all the `$reset` and `$touch` I've tried haven't work.